# Can't access values Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I am trying to start a project with Angular2 and ES6 but I have an issue trying to access my data.

index.js

```
import {zoneJs} from 'zone.js'
import {reflectMetadata} from 'reflect-metadata'
import {bootstrap}  from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {HelloWorld} from './hello_world';
bootstrap(HelloWorld);
```

hello_world.js

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  // Declare the tag name in index.html to where the component attaches
  selector: 'hello-world',
  // Location of the template for this component
  templateUrl: 'dist/template/hello_world.html'
})

export class HelloWorld {
  yourName = ''
}
```

hello_world.hlml

```
<label>Name:</label>
<!-- data-bind to the input element; store value in yourName -->
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
<hr>
<!-- conditionally display `yourName` -->
<h1 [hidden]="!yourName">Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
```

The template is rendre in my webpage, but I have the following error

```
script.js:17 EXCEPTION: No value accessor for '' in [yourNames in s@2:19]
```

Comment: was just due to an uglify issue

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine for me -> [Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/YSFyIO?p=preview)

I just had to remove the backticks from

```
<!-- conditionally display `yourName` -->
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this line from HTML, it should start working,

```
<!-- conditionally display `yourName` -->
```